# Bare bones xcode project generated as a SingleViewApplication <invalid loc>

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

I have a larger project that takes 20 minutes to compile. So now I am experimenting with various coding styles to figure out what's the problem.
So I created a bare bones project, and I see that it has a lot of  logs.

I added the `other swift flags` `-Xfrontend` and `-debug-time-function-bodies` to see the build time

```
0.15ms  <invalid loc>   init?(rawValue: Int)
0.08ms  <invalid loc>   get {}
0.10ms  <invalid loc>   init?(rawValue: Int)
0.05ms  <invalid loc>   get {}
0.81ms  <invalid loc>   get {}
0.18ms  <invalid loc>   get {}
0.38ms  <invalid loc>   init()
0.12ms  <invalid loc>   init(_ rawValue: String)
0.11ms  <invalid loc>   init(rawValue: String)
0.09ms  <invalid loc>   init?(rawValue: UInt)
0.08ms  <invalid loc>   get {}
0.04ms  <invalid loc>   get {}
0.02ms  <invalid loc>   get {}
0.02ms  <invalid loc>   get {}
0.47ms  <invalid loc>   init()
0.25ms  <invalid loc>   init()
0.09ms  <invalid loc>   init()
0.11ms  <invalid loc>   init(_ rawValue: String)
0.10ms  <invalid loc>   init(rawValue: String)
0.04ms  <invalid loc>   get {}
0.03ms  <invalid loc>   get {}
0.05ms  <invalid loc>   get {}
0.04ms  <invalid loc>   get {}
0.04ms  <invalid loc>   get {}
0.04ms  <invalid loc>   get {}
0.03ms  <invalid loc>   get {}
0.03ms  <invalid loc>   get {}
0.04ms  <invalid loc>   get {}
```

Is this at all a problem?

Comment: Hi, I am curious if you solved this problem as I am now facing the same issue?

Comment: fix all the warnings you have and see if that helps. It worked for us.

Comment: I'm seeing the same (with similar 8-15 minute compile time...) I have some warnings, but none in the relevant file(s)